# VBA select columns with Text contains and toggle button for hiding all other columns

Tags: vba, toggle, multiple-columns, hide

Thanks in advance. I need to create a toggle button to hide/unhide all columns based on whether text of the column header Row(1:1) contains 'x'

It would help my purposes if these column headers where formatted differently.

I started with the Macro1(for conditional formatting based on text contains) and tried to use this code to help write the rest, but have not yet succeeded. Below for reference.

Main goal is to create function to show any columns where header Is Yellow and hide all other columns.

```
Function IsYellow(Rge As Range) As Boolean

If Rng.Cells.Interior.Color = 10284031 Then IsYellow = True

End Function

Sub Hide_x()

'Description: This macro will loop through a row and
'hide the column if the cell in row 1 of the column
'has the value of X.



Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Rows("1:1")
        If IsYellow(c) = False Then
            'The following line changes the hidden property to
            'the opposite of it's current setting for the column.
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            '= Not c.EntireColumn.Hidden.
        End If
    Next c


End Sub


PLEASE HELP! 



FYI


///////
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="TEXT", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16754788
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub



'RGB(255, 235, 156)
```

Comment: `IsYellow = Rng.DisplyFormat.Interior.Color = 10284031` if you're using CF you need to use DisplayFormat.

Comment: Thanks, tried - but I think I'm missing the correct way to loop through a rows and select cell/ need if the cell is yellow add then do function to its column. somewhere in Rng is the error ---> to replace the "ActiveCell" here "ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It will toggle the visibility of all columns where the value in Row1 contains "x"

```vb
Sub TogglexHidden()

    'Description: This macro will loop through a row and
    'hide/unhide the column if the cell in row 1 of the column
    'contains X.
    Dim c As Range, rngHeaders As Range, hiding As Boolean, foundFirst As Boolean
    
    With ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'or specify some other sheet
        'set the range to oop over (not the whole row)
        Set rngHeaders = .Range(.Cells(1), .Cells(.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        rngHeaders.Select
    End With
    
    For Each c In rngHeaders
        If UCase(c.Value) Like "*X*" Then  'checking directly for "x"
        'If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 10284031 Then 'if you prefer to use color to check
            If Not foundFirst Then
                'are we hiding, or unhiding ? (based on whether the first
                '  one we found was already hidden or not)
                hiding = Not c.EntireColumn.Hidden
                foundFirst = True 'have now checked the first column with "x"
            End If
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = hiding 'set the visibility
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```